# Is it possible to have type comparison in PDDL?

Tags: pddl

For example, if I declare types as such:

```
:types
   bag
   light heavy - bag
```

That is to say there are two types of bags, *light* and *heavy*. Would it be possible within an action to check if a variable of type *bag* is of type *light* without having an instance of *light* to compare to?

I know it's possible to have an equality comparison as such:

```
(when ( = ?light ?bag))
```

but this checks if two variables have the same value, rather than the same type.

I tried `(when ( = light ?bag))` and even though the planner doesn't throw up errors it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The short answer is no. There is no built-in possibility in PDDL to compare types (or, more specifically, to test whether a variable is of a specific type). There are workarounds for this, but maybe you will be able to derive them for yourself. If not, just say so, maybe I'll find the time to explain.

Comment: Thanks, I've came up with a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to Prof. Chaos' comment where they state this is not possible, I've derived a workaround where we create the predicate `(is_light ?x - light)` and use `(when (is_light ?lightobj) (dosomething))` in the action. The predicate is utilised in the problem file when initialising *light* objects.